# How to concatenate data of multiple ReyclerView Adapters

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a problem and I don't know how to create a layout like this in a right way.

[image]

I draw it myself)) It seems like a `recyclerView` with multiple view types. BUT. The 'first items' data and 'second items' data I'm getting from different sources. In the middle of them I have a separator line. Also the `recyclerview` of SecondItems has pagination, but the `recyclerview` of first items hasn't. If I'm not getting firstItems data, I have to hide firstItems and Separator line from my view. So how can I implement it in a right way? Create a `nestedScrollView` and add 2 `recyclerViews` there? One for firstItems and second for secondItems. Or create only 1 recyclerView with multiple view types, but there are also many cases, e.g. my connection is slow, and I'm getting second items data only after 3 seconds after getting first items data or vice versa and I don't have to upate the whole adapter.Or assume I scroll the view to bottom. So I'm using pagination only for second items. And after that I have to update only secondItems data, without updating the whole adapter data. I think you understand. If you need some more details, you can leave any contact and I will contact you asap. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if he screen is too small to hold all of the first items? Does the top scroll separately?

Comment: There 2 ways in my opinion. Once to add all them in one nestedscrollview and turn off recyclerview nested scroll, or make one recyclerview with multiple view types, but that will occure problems as I described.

Comment: but I'm trying to appraise you of real-world problems. As developers we're used to having huge monitors, but our customers might not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new [`MergeAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/MergeAdapter) class to concatenate multiple RecyclerView Adapters together.  Note that it's currently only available in the alpha.  See [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a) for an article on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a recyclerView with different view types. Your first item should be a different view type, second item should be a different view type and also your seperator line should be a different view type. At the end, your layout must have only a recyclerView, nothing else. No scrollview or no other views etc.  Check here https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-multiple-view-holder-af798458763b

Comment: In that case I can't update only the second view, under you must also like, as it's one adapter. Also I can't use pagination for only 1 view type, because it's a whole adapter))